# Как не сворачивать окно на втором мониторе?

Tags: windows

Когда нажимать WIN+d окна сворачиваются на двух мониторах сразу, хотя такой эффект хотелось бы видеть только на активном мониторе. Можно ли это как-то поменять?

Comment: Вряд ли. Win + D показывает рабочий стол. Вот вам и показывает весь рабочий стол.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант WIN + Home. Но не очень удобно. Но опять же, наверное можно как-то поменять на более удобную клавишу